# App not compatible with buildpack when trying to deploy rails/react app

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku, npm, deployment

I have recently deployed a rails app on heroku with no issues however, now I'm trying to deploy a rails/react app on heroku and I am having a hell of a time. Could anyone help point me in the right direction? I have added the nodejs and ruby buildpacks for heroku. I'm afraid i'm missing something to connect the two environments together or something. Here is the current error I'm getting, I'd appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

````
```remote: -----> Build
remote:        Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > gone-fishin-frontend@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_0df26b25
remote:        > npm run build && npm install
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > gone-fishin-frontend@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_0df26b25
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Compiled successfully.
remote:        
remote:        File sizes after gzip:
remote:        
remote:          63.32 KB  build/static/js/2.b0463501.chunk.js
remote:          2.48 KB   build/static/js/main.61d8b38a.chunk.js
remote:          783 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.44a3a2b0.js
remote:          690 B     build/static/css/main.10cdadf4.chunk.css
remote:        
remote:        The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
remote:        You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
remote:        
remote:        The build folder is ready to be deployed.
remote:        You may serve it with a static server:
remote:        
remote:          npm install -g serve
remote:          serve -s build
remote:        
remote:        Find out more about deployment here:
remote:        
remote:          bit.ly/CRA-deploy
remote:        
remote:        removed 35 packages and audited 1737 packages in 14.177s
remote:        
remote:        71 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 35 packages and audited 1737 packages in 12.724s
remote:        
remote:        71 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to gonefishin-frontend.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/gonefishin-frontend.git```
````

**And here is my package.json**

````
```{
  "name": "gone-fishin-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.6",
    "node": "14.5.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm install",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```
````

Comment: You say this is a react/rails app, but the package file looks like a vanilla react/redux app -- none of the standard ``@rails`` packages, etc. Is this actually a standard React app that talks to a Rails API app? If so you shouldn't be building with the ruby build pack, since it requires you to have a Gemfile.

Comment: @rmlockerd Sorry, it is a react/redux frontend that talks to a rails API backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

See the Heroku article link.

You can find the [Ruby `detect` script here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/main/bin/detect).

Your project is not compatible with the Ruby buildpack because it is missing `Gemfile` at the root directory of your git repo.